# Cakephp Favicon on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp, favicon

I'm trying to setup favicon on IE, since I allways get the warnings saying that it's not being accessed.

```
2017-03-06 19:43:25 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Favicon.ico could not be found.
```

On other browsers, they are working no problem.

I have the following code

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="url/favicon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="url/favicon/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="url/favicon/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

Yet, it stills gives the error.

Any ideias?

Comment: You've replaced the part of the code that causes the error with "direct URL". Pretty sure we're not going to be able to assist.

Comment: @Dave you were right, fixed it! :)

Comment: I don't think many versions of IE support PNG fav icons, have you tried an ico format already?

Comment: IE only supports [**PNG favicons**](http://caniuse.com/link-icon-png) as of version 11... and that's why it's important to always supply version information alongside of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the answers

Fixed the problem with routes

```
Router::redirect(
    '/favicon.ico',
   'url.ico', array('status' => 302)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Create an icon file named `favicon.ico` and put it at the root of your site.

**In details**

By convention, IE looks for `/favicon.ico` when it visits a site. Modern versions also supports PNG icons, so this issue is harmless and can be ignored.

What you can do to fix this issue:

- Provide a `favicon.ico` at the root of your web site. This will prevent the failure while giving some browsers what they are looking for.
- Make CakePHP ignore the error. Apparently the access tricks CakePHP, which thinks this must be routed to some PHP code. If CakePHP could consider this access as what it is (ie. an access to a static file), it would just end up as it should: a regular 404 error. No one like 404, but at least this is the right behavior, unlike a quest for an hypothetical controller named Favicon.ico.